# In python check if a list item is in the mo/dd/yy format?

Tags: python, database, list, format

I have a list of data:

```
['12/43/45', 'name', 'fg34534543', 'SOME DESCRIPTION', '2', '4.00', '2.00', 'y', '7.00', '342.00', 'name']
```

I need to check if the first item is in the format mm/dd/yy. Since the actual dates will change with every list and it would be impractical to check it against a list of all dates from the beginning of time until now, how could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the datetime package to validate the date field:

```
In [102]: def validate(date_text):
     ...:     try:
     ...:         datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text,'%m/%d/%y')
     ...:     except:
     ...:         raise ValueError("Incorrect data format, should be mm/dd/yy")
     ...:
newlist= ['12/34/45', 'name', 'fg34534543', 'SOME DESCRIPTION', '2', '4.00', '2.00', 'y', '7.00', '342.00', '
     ...: name']

In [105]: validate(newlist[0])

ValueError: Incorrect data format, should be mm/dd/yy
```

It would give an error if the field is not a valid date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions, e.g.

```
import re

if re.match(r'^\d\d/\d\d/\d\d$', data[0]):
   # do something
```

The `\d` matches any digit, `^` and `$` mark beginning and end of string respectively.